# how to add java in install created to make a exe setup

Tags: java, installation, setuptools, setup-deployment

I want to make a exe setup using install creator software but i don't know how to set java min and max version validation in to it can any body help me
i use it bcz in my exe setup contain some folder. and other exe setup install don't give me any opption to add folder in to it

Comment: You can use launch4j

Comment: but that not having any option to add a folder

Comment: did you create your exe file?